# Add a description to python dataframe before column headers when exporting?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, text

I have a dataframe with thousands of rows of data that I am exporting as a txt. file that can then be imported into a software at work.

The way the other software reads data requires there to be a specific description of text (split into rows) found before the dataframe column headers. I am exporting my dataframe using the following code:

```
 with open(r'test.txt', 'w') as f:
    df.to_string(f, col_space=10, index=False)
```

Is there a way to add content to my code such that my exported file has a few rows of text before the actual data and column headers are presented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write to the file directly before the `df.to_string()` gets written to the file. W3 Schools has a [simple walkthrough](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp).

```
f.write("Whatever your header text looks like(Line 1)\n")
f.write("Whatever your header text looks like(Line 2)\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is. You can add attributes

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([])
df.attrs['my attributes`] = 'this is the content'
```